# cant send variable to php side (Two problems)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, variables

I am trying to move a variable to the server side but i cant get it to work.
I have got a sample code in one of those threads and it (almost) works.

my current code:

```
public void mahGPSbutton() {


    Button myGPS_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.GPS_button);
    myGPS_button.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
    myGPS_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                                                                                              //#
        public void onClick(View v) {   
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); //#
            LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {                                                      //#
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    double MyLat = location.getLatitude();
                    double MyLong = location.getLongitude();
                    double MyAlt = location.getAltitude();
                    String MyProvider = location.getProvider();
                    float MyAccuracy = location.getAccuracy();
                }
                    public void sender() {
                    String url = "www.IP/FOLDER/Binder.php?myLat="+ MyLat;
                    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
                    request.setURI(null);
                    try {
                        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(request);
                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}                                    //#
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}                                                             //#
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
                //#
            };                                                                                                                //#
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
                                                                                                              //#
        }                                                                                                                     //#
    }); 
}
```

Problems are on line & line;

```
String url = "www.IP/FOLDER/Binder.php?myLat="+ MyLat;
request.setURI(null);
```

MyLat gives me an error: "MyLat cannot be resolved to a variable" with i understand why it gives me this but i dont know a way to fix it.
and then
request.setURI(null);
this is okay, but when i change null into URI it gives me the following error:
"The method setURI(URI) in the type HttpRequestBase is not applicable for the arguments"
With i dont get it, and dont know a way to fix it...

any help will be fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing Null to HttpGet.setURI(null); you should pass URI as:

```
String url = "www.IP/FOLDER/Binder.php?myLat="+ MyLat;
URI url_uri = new URI(url); 
request.setURI(url_uri);
```

or use  [HttpGet(String uri)](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpGet.html#HttpGet%28java.lang.String%29) to create instance :

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
```

Comment: Hello, thank you, i have got it to work now, but i still have problems, i cant see the variable inside the php file, it just stays empthy.
The link i try is : www.IP/FOLDER/Binder.php?myProvider= with is correct right?

(sorry i forgot to tell i make it much simpler for my self, instead of using a numbers, i use now a text (string variable)...